# Select First Two Rows of Child Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return one row of data for a parent record. The parent record can have many child records, but I only want the first two rows (and the total count of rows for the parent).

Here is an example of data:

```
ParentTable
+-----------------------+
| ParentId | ParentData |
+-----------------------+
|        1| Stuff       |
|        2| Things      |
|        3| Foo         |
|        4| Bar         |
-------------------------

ChildTable
+-------------------------------+
| ChildId | ParentId| ChildData |
+-------------------------------+
|       1 |       1 | Alpha     |
|       2 |       1 | Bravo     |
|       3 |       2 | Charlie   |
|       4 |       2 | Delta     |
|       5 |       2 | Echo      |
|       6 |       3 | Foxtrot   |
---------------------------------
```

And here is my desired result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| ParentId | ParentData | ChildData1 | ChildData2 | ChildRowCount |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | Stuff      | Alpha      | Bravo      |             2 |
|        2 | Things     | Charlie    | Delta      |             3 |
|        3 | Foo        | Foxtrot    | (NULL)     |             1 |
|        4 | Bar        | (NULL)     | (NULL)     |             0 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure if this needs a sub-query, a temp table, or a JOIN or GROUP BY of some sort.

In the end I need to use this in SSIS, but I'm starting with a query and going to go from there.

What kind of query can accomplish this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Added SQL Server because of mention of SSIS... please tag with the *specific* appropriate tags.

Comment: *first 2 rows* how? what specifies the 2 records to be picked up from the child table?

Comment: You'll want to look into *windowing functions* and how to use them (this site has PLENTY of examples!), more specifically `row_number()`. Once you have a row number for your "child" data, it's pretty easy to filter for `rn <= 2`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug SQL Server is the DMBS.  I didn't think it was relevant, but I was wrong.

Comment: @vkp The "first two rows" will be the order they are added, so a sort on the PK of the ChildTable or a date also in that table could be used.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm not familiar with "windowing functions".  I'll search around and educate myself if I can.

Comment: That'll be `select rn = row_number() over (order by ChildId)`, as part of your subquery (or CTE) ..although I hate to give meaning to a PK column, it's like making an assumption that's just waiting to blow up in my face.. don't you have a `DateInserted` control column you could sort with? If you want them in the order they were inserted in, a timestamp control column would be more reliable IMO.

Comment: Thank you to @Mat'sMug and "a_horse_with_no_name" for your comments.  I'm trying to get better at asking questions.  All feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table to number the childdata table's rows and count the number of childid's per parent. `left join` this to the parenttable and get the desired result.

```
select distinct p.parentid,p.parentdata,
max(case when c.rnum =1 then c.childata end) over(partition by p.parentid,p.parentdata) as childdata1,
max(case when c.rnum =2 then c.childata end) over(partition by p.parentid,p.parentdata) as childdata2,
coalesce(c.childrowcount,0) as childrowcount
from parenttable p
left join (select c.*
           ,row_number() over(partition by parentid order by childid) as rnum
           ,count(*) over(partition by parentid) as childrowcount
           from childtable c) c
on c.parentid=p.parentid
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution.  I'm getting the correct "ChildData1", "ChildData2" and "ChildRowCount" values, but the rows aren't grouping.  So going off the sample data from the question, I have three rows of ParentId = 2.  I tried using a "GROUP BY" at the end of the entire statement, but I'm not sure what columns to include. Can I use the aliases in the GROUP BY?

Comment: That was it.  Thank you for your replies, @vkp.